# Continuous function in R Programming

Tags: r, function, vector, continuous

I'm trying to code the following continuous function in R Programming.

[image: This is an image of my f(x)]

I was trying to create a function called `fun1` that takes a single argument `vecA`. I want the function to return the values of f(x) evaluated at the values of `vecA`.

```
fun1(vecA) <- function(x){
   x^2+2x+3
 }
```

I don't know how I can continue it.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally your function should be able to take vectorized input, in which case you should use `ifelse` or `case_when`.

For example:

```r
f <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x < 0, x^2 + 2*x + 3,
         ifelse(x >= 2, x^2 + 4 * x - 7,
                x + 3))
}
```

Or

```r
f <- function(x) {
  dplyr::case_when(x < 0 ~ x^2 + 2*x + 3,
                   x > 2 ~ x^2 + 4 * x - 7,
                   TRUE  ~ x + 3)
}
```

both of which produce the same output. We can see what the function looks like by doing:

```r
plot(f, xlim = c(-5, 5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Try studying the patterns here:

```
fun1 <- function(x){
   if (x < 0) {
     x^2+2*x+3
   } else if (x < 2) {
     x + 3
   } else {
     # Your turn
   }
}
```